# Vertical distance between title parts is larger than the distance between title and license attribution

Tags: bug, design, timeline, responsive-design

In timeline for questions with long titles on devices with narrow screen the vertical distance between parts of the title is larger than between title and the licensing attribution. E.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/151861/timeline):

> [image: Red distance > blue distance]

Red distance is larger than the blue distance, however distance marked red belongs to the same thing (title), but the blue distance is between different things.

Thus, visually items located closer considered to the same item, but it's not.